# MongoDB does not connect with options parameter

Tags: php, mongodb, mongohq

I am trying to connect with options parameter but it does not connect

```
try
  { 
    $connection_url = "mongodb://{$dbuser}:{$dbpass}@{$dburl}:{$dbport}/{$dbname}";
    $m = new MongoClient($connection_url, 
                          array('connectTimeoutMS'=>30000,
                                'socketTimeoutMS'=>30000)
                       );

   }
   catch ( MongoConnectionException $e ) 
   {
     echo $e->getMessage();

   }
   catch ( MongoException $e ) 
   {
     echo $e->getMessage();
   } 
   catch ( Exception $e ) 
   {
     echo $e->getMessage();
   }
```

this code simply goes to exception with no message.

If I remove options parameters it makes a connection to mongodb server.

Why it does not connect with parameter option?

If I use another way to pass `options` parameter

```
$connection_url = "mongodb://{$dbuser}:{$dbpass}@{$dburl}:{$dbport}
                 /{$dbname}?connectTimeoutMS=30000&socketTimeoutMS=30000";
$m = new MongoClient($connection_url);
```

It through error

> 'MongoConnectionException' with message '- Found unknown connection
>   string option 'connectTimeoutMS' with value '>30000''

Neither way is working with options parameter.

Mongodb is on mongohq.com

Comment: What's the type of exception? It should have a type

Comment: It is `MongoConnectionException`

Comment: I wonder if mongohq could be doing this. I have never used `connectTimeoutMS` so I don't actually know what the timeout limit is on it

Answer (score 0):

This is actually documented as not supported in the PHP manual page for [MongoClient](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongoclient.construct.php).

Also as mentioned in the ChangeLog at the bottom of the page, support for the options (option argument style) for the options you are using was only added at version 1.3.4 of the driver. So you may need to check your driver version.

Comment: my driver version is up to date. It is 1.4.5

Comment: @ShaktiSingh Then this does seem unusual as I have tested this myself. The error given would be emitted from the PHP driver on options checking. It is not thrown from an external source.